# How to call Cocoa Methods from Applescript under OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

In former OS X versions (pre 10.6) it was possible to call Cocoa methods via the "call method" command in applescript ("Applescript Studio").
E.g. this way:

`set theURL to "http://www.apple.com"
set URLWithString to (call method "stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:" of theURL with parameter 30)`

The script interpreter in the "Applescript Editor" (10.6) does not understand the command "call method". - Is there an equivalent for "Applescript Editor" (10.6)?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem is the difference between AppleScript Studio and AppleScript Editor; the former should support `call method` in any (recent?) version of OS X, while the latter won't in any.

Comment: Hello Antal S-Z! Exactly this is my impression. But I think it should be possible to bridge Applescript and Cocoa in an alternative way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "call method" in applescript. Apple gave that ability to Automator and we can access that ability from applescript by using the "Automator Runner" application. I just showed this to someone recently. See my post #4 [here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=115343).

So to answer your question, just put your "call method" code inside a **tell application "Automator Runner"** tell block.

Comment: I'm not sure when this stopped working, but as of Mac OS X 10.9.1 telling Automator Runner to "call method" results in an AppleScript compilation error. I don't think there is currently any way to "call method" without installing a helper AppleScriptObjC application that can receive that command.

Answer (score 1):

**AppleScript Studio** I thought was done in **Xcode** not AppleScript Editor. Code in **AppleScript Editor** can only be saved as **scripts** and the language is just plain **AppleScript**.

If you're doing this is **Xcode, on 10.6, AppleScript Studio no longer exists. It's now AppleScript-Obj-C**

I don't know an exact answer.. but...

If you take `- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender` in AppleScript-Obj-C, if I have a property linked to a window in Xcode I just go: `myWindowProperty's makeKeyAndOrderFront_(sender)`

I hope this helped at least a bit!